# DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works once?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I'm trying to create a counter to increment by one each time I send an email. My DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement works only once. After the sent field updates to a value of 2, running the query multiple times makes no updates. I'm not sure why? I would expect to be able to update the sent field as many times as needed.

```
INSERT INTO remind_sync(studentid, sent)
VALUES(8, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
    sent =
VALUES(sent) +1


CREATE TABLE `remind_sync` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sent` smallint(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `remind_sync`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `studentid` (`studentid`);


ALTER TABLE `remind_sync`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost meaningless and probably best omitted

Comment: It looks like it updates to me. I suspect you want to increase the value stored in the database by 1, rather than setting it to '1 plus the value in the insert' - so `sent = sent + 1`

Comment: @Strawberry - Thank you! That solved my issue!!!

Answer (score 1):

> After the sent field updates to a value of 2, running the query multiple times makes no updates.

Every time you run your insert with a `sent` value of `1`, you get `1+1` or `2`.  `sent = sent+ values(sent)` would continue to include the current value of `sent`, thus incrementing as desired.

While we're at it,

```sql
ALTER TABLE `remind_sync`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `studentid` (`studentid`);


ALTER TABLE `remind_sync`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Why not just this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `remind_sync` (
    `id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)
```